# Good reads on app deeplinking for oauth flows with popular apps like Facebook or LinkedIn?

Tags: ios, mobile, oauth, google-oauth, linkedin-api

Is there any good material available on how to approach oauth flows with mobile deeplinking inApp?
I have seen several bad implementations where users land on a web form to login to linkedin even if the user had the linkedin App installed.
Is there any general doc on how to deeplink to apps like facebook and linkedin generally?

Also, does this work for the mobile web?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? What do you mean by "deeplinking inApp"?

Comment: @JohnHanley I want the user to authenticate through LinkedIn without having to log in but by using the app the user has already installed. clearer now?